# ruby-1.9.2-head gem usage issues

Tags: ubuntu, rubygems, rvm, ruby-1.9

I've been having difficulty with running `gem` commands with ruby 1.9.x and any version of rubygems.  I've been using rvm to handle all the installation of ruby and rubygems, but I can't seem to isolate the issue:

```
rvm use 1.8.7
Using /home/kelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p352
which gem
/home/kelly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.8.7-p352/bin/gem
gem -v
1.8.10
gem install rails #success!

rvm use 1.9.2
Using /home/kelly/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290
which gem
/home/kelly/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/gem
gem -v
1.8.10
gem install rails
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `each' for "http://rubygems.org":String
```

I'm running a 64-bit Ubuntu 11.04 install.  Any pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After editing my `~/.gemrc` configuration file to specify `source` instead of `sources`, rubygems was able to load my sources as an `Array` instead of a `String`:

**before**

```
---
:backtrace: false
:benchmark: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:sources: http://rubygems.org
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```

**after**

```
---
:backtrace: false
:benchmark: false
:bulk_threshold: 1000
:source: http://rubygems.org
:update_sources: true
:verbose: true
```